# Why am I not getting queue messages using Azure Service Bus Queue?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I was following the documentation for How to use Service Bus Queues on Azure documentation.

I created 2 different web applications to test out using Queues for a project I need to work on. I created one project to publish messages into the queue and then the other application is supposed to listen to the Queue to process the messages.

I successfully was able to publish messages to the Queue and I can see that the queue length in the Azure portal says 3. So there should be 3 messages waiting for me to process. However, when I run the web application that has the QueueClient.OnMessage no messages are getting pushed. Is there something else that I am missing when doing this?

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, "TestQueue");

        var options = new OnMessageOptions
        {
            AutoComplete = false,
            AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
        };

        // Callback to handle received messages.
        client.OnMessage((message) =>
        {
            try
            {
                // Process message from queue.
                var messageBody = message.GetBody<string>();
                // Remove message from queue.
                message.Complete();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Indicates a problem, unlock message in queue.
                message.Abandon();
            }
        }, options);
    }
}
```

The ConnectionStrings are the same in both applications so there is no differences there.
Here is the code that I am using to connect and send a message to the Queue.

```
var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ConnectionString, "TestQueue");
        var message = new BrokeredMessage(value);

        message.Properties["TestProperty"] = "This is a test";
        message.Properties["UserId"] = "TestUser";

        client.Send(message);
```

If anyone has any insights into why this is happening it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Code looks correct to me. Where is your QueueClient code being run in your WebApp? Are you sure your QueueClient instance is isn't being prematurely disposed? You might consider hoisting your code out into a little sandbox Conosole app to verify that the code + connections are working as expected.

Comment: Be aware that the portal includes dead lettered messages in the count of messages it is displaying. I would recommend [ServiceBusExplorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) for debugging Service Bus problems. Using this I would verify that the messages have not been moved to the dead letter queue. It will also allow you to view the retry count on messages so you will be able to see if the message is being picked up or not and possibly abandoned due to an exception.

Comment: @AlexS Thanks for recommending ServiceBusExplorer that did help me understand my issue. And it seems that this will be very helpful for future use of Azure Service Bus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that I was running into a 407 Proxy Authentication Required error when trying to connect to the service bus that I noticed when trying to debug this through a different application.
All I had to do was add the following to the system.net section of the web.config once I did that I was able to receive messages.

```
<defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
<proxy bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="True"/>
</defaultProxy>
```